# What can I learn from the "The system has recovered from a serious error." dialog?

Tags: windows

Occasionally I see an error dialog that looks a lot like the one pictued below.

[image]

I want to understand what went wrong, so I click to see what data the error report contains.

The next dialog that I see looks something like the one pictured below.

[image]

What information does each of these values represent?

- BCCode
- BCP1
- BCP2
- BCP3
- BCP4
- OSVer
- SP
- Product

How can I use these values to better understand what the cause of the error was?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What information does each of these
>   values represent?

- `BCCode` = Bug Check Code
- `BCP1-4` = Bug Check Parameter

They represent what you will see in a typical BSOD - a STOP error code followed by 4 parameters:

[image]

The other values identify the operating system, service pack and the product causing the crash:

- `OSVer` = OS Version
- `SP` = Service Pack

> How can I use these values to better
>   understand what the cause of the error
>   was?

You may use NirSoft's **[BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html)** to interpret minidump files which are created during 'blue screen of death' crashes or check the [bugcodes.h](http://owbuilder.malakovi.cz/snapshot/h/nt/ddk/bugcodes.h) file (open with Notepad) for a full list of bug check codes.

Answer (score 0):

You won't learn much from their "error reports", but whenever there is a serious STOP error like that, there will also be an event in the system event log which is more verbose.